# ActionScript - Click and Go to URL, Open on current tab

Tags: html, flash, iframe, actionscript, google-swiffy

I have created a flash animation with actionscript (which I don't know very much about) and I've converted it to html5 with swiffy.

I was wondering is it possible that when a "click and go to web page" button is clicked that the URL is opened in the current tab and not a new one? I've tried googling it and nothing comes up.

This is the actionscript as it appears in flash.. I'll spare you the code swiffy generates!

```
forumgo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToWebPage);

function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage(event:MouseEvent):void
{
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.adobe.com"), "_blank");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the "_blank" to "_self", it should work when converted.

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.adobe.com"), "_self");
```

Comment: is _self better than _parent?

Comment: not better, depends on what you need to do. "_self" specifies the current frame in the current window, "_parent" specifies the parent of the current frame.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! It should be _parent instead of _blank

```
forumgo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToWebPage);

function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage(event:MouseEvent):void
{
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.adobe.com"), "_parent");
}
```